# Convert column of Unix to date time

Tags: r, datetime, unix

Trying to convert a full column of Unix into date time in R. I've been able to use

```
as.POSIXlt(x, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

to convert Unix. But now I'm trying to convert a whole column of Unix into date time using:

```
as.POSIXct(x$time, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Which gives me:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

What is the best way to be doing this?

Comment: I only use `origin` when trying to convert "seconds epoch", though it is not an error to use it here. This way is fine, but the error indicates that there is at least one element in the column that is not formatted correctly, as can be seen with `as.POSIXct(c("1970-02-03","aa"), origin="1970-01-01")`.

Comment: As far as I know, `as.POSIXct` should already be vectorized, and your call should be working.  Maybe your data has a problem.

Comment: please provide some sample values of `x`

Comment: @MichaelChirico 1433996194 is one Unix from the dataset that I've been able to successfully convert with `as.POSIXlt(x, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: try `structure(x, class = c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt'))`, does printing this give any errors? If not, try `as.POSIXlt(structure(x, class = c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico That doesn't print any errors but now every time is `1969-12-31 19:00:01 EST`

Comment: @harkintr, there is something wrong with at least one of your data. At least one of your assumptions about your data are incorrect. That kind of error doesn't happen with negative, `NA`, or other type of `numeric`, so it seems obvious that it is not `numeric`. This means you either have `factor` or `character`, in which case you need to find which of your strings is wrong. If you give a sample of your data (as MichaelChirico suggested), perhaps we can help you (1) find which elements are wrong, and then (2) how to handle/fix them.

Answer (score 0):

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x$time), origin="1970-01-01")
```